# Creating second zygote process for the same app in Android

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I need two zygote process to fork the system two times for an app to handle different level of inputs.

I see in the ZygoteInit.java file that creating a secondary zygote depends on --abi-list. If there is any unsupprted abi then zygote-secondary will be created but it will also be killed immediately in the function waitForSecondaryZygote() without doing anything. The socket is killed there.

What is the need of the secondary Zygote?
How can I create another Zygote?
Is Zygote thread safe?

Comment: Why don't you create another process using "process" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19510055/what-is-the-purpose-of-defined-process-in-service-class-of-manifest-file-in-andr) ?

Comment: I am not creating any app or this is not related to any app. Its a research related to security leakage research. This will be a change in android framework for all apps.

Answer (score 2):

Devices that support multiple ABI's may have multiple Zygotes with an application running on a different Zygote. Android allows the developer to select ABI targets in their code, so switching from one ABI target to another may require a new Zygote fork. Since running both applications concurrently would cause problems, the secondary zygote process should be closed when creating a new one.

A good way to illustrate this is to see a diff when CyanogenMod integrated the changes to support multiple ABI configurations on a single device:

https://gitlab.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/commit/402120a2236b294dff9a51461cb22400a6ef67f6

Notice that the Zygote process is waiting for the secondary process to die before creating the new one.

For example, a device that supports ARM and Mips may have an app that utilizes one at times or the other (this is rare). If the APK or device configuration changes, then when a request to Zygote ARM starts, it should check for the app process in Zygote Mips before starting a new one.

And yes, Zygote is thread safe.

EDIT:

Note that the `Build` object has a `SUPPORTED_ABIS` list that is defined as:

> An ordered list of ABIs supported by this device.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#SUPPORTED_ABIS

I used ARM and Mips as an illustration - a more obvious example might be x86 and x86_64, similar to how Windows run both 32-bit and 64-bit code on the same device.

Comment: This is having no relation with what an app uses. Its related to machine instruction(ABIs). When Zygote starts AndroidRuntime supplies the supported ABIs to the zygote. When the apps are running then apk file code will be converted to the supported ABI. Which device supports both ARM and MIPS?

Comment: This answer is underrated. Thanks for such detail info.